# Check zero Equivalent of time.Time when retrieving from mongodb Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, time, mongo-go

So I have a very Simple Struct which is persisted in the MongoDB

```
type Test struct {
    ID                  string                            `bson:"_id"`
    Status              string                            `bson:"status"`
    TestTime            time.Time                         `bson:"TestTime"`
}
```

While Retrieving I want to make sure that I am not retrieving any value whose TestTime is not initialized i.e exclude missing/zero equivalent value of time.Time

```
filter := bson.M{"status": "Ready"}
```

Any advice on how should I update my filter criteria here

```
cursor, err := r.store.Db.Collection("testCollection").Find(ctx, filter)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = cursor.All(ctx, result)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
   }
```

Comment: You can specify `{ testTime: { $ne: null } }`, `{ testTime: { $exists: true } }` filters to check the field value is not null or the field exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you inserted your documents into MongoDB.

If you inserted them using your `Test` struct where you did not change the `TestTime` field, that means it will have the [zero value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time), which will get saved into MongoDB. In MongoDB it has a value of:

```
TestTime: ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
```

To filter out such times, in Go again use the zero value of `time.Time` like this:

```
filter := bson.M{
    "status":   "Ready",
    "TestTime": bson.M{"$ne": time.Time{}},
}
```

If you inserted documents in some other way where `TestTime` may be `null` or non-existing, you may account for that like this:

```
filter := bson.M{
    "status": "Ready",
    "TestTime": bson.M{
        "$nin": []any{time.Time{}, nil},
    },
}
```